# Zend Framework 2 'Twig' view passing variable to a partial

Tags: php, zend-framework2, twig, partial

I am converting a ZF2 "filename.phtml" view to a "filename.twig" view. I am needing help knowing how to pass a variable to a partial.  The nature of the partial provides a variety of "social network" share type buttons.  What I am giving the partial is the URL of the web page being accessed to "share".

The code I am trying to convert:

```
echo $this->partial('partial/socialnetworkshare', array('web_page' => $this->url('main-prayersfortoday', array('prayer_reference' => $this->prayer_reference ))));
```

I haven't correctly figured out how to pass the value of "$this->prayer_reference".  This is what I have tried:

```
{{ partial('partial/socialnetworkshare', {'web_page' : url('main-prayersfortoday') , 'prayer_reference' : prayer_reference }) }}
```

prayer_ministry is to match this route:

```
'main-prayersfortoday'     => array(
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'       => '/prayers-for-today[/:prayer_reference]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'prayer_reference' => '[0-9]*'
        ),
        'defaults'    => array(
            'controller' => 'Main\Controller\Main',
            'action'     => 'prayersfortoday'
        )
    )
),
```

The value of "prayer_ministry" is passing through this controller:

```
$viewModel
    ->setTemplate('main/main/prayersfortodaydocument')
    ->setVariable('prayer_reference', $this->params()->fromRoute('prayer_reference'))
    ->setVariable('document', $document);
```

I very much appreciate your help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something like this, using the [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) tag:

```
{% include 'partial/socialnetworkshare' with {
  'web_page': path('main-prayersfortoday'),
  'prayer_reference': prayer_reference
} %}
```

In Symfony, we have Twig extensions which provide the Twig `path()` function similar to `$this->url()` in Zend. You may need to register you own Twig extension to provide this in Zend.